# Equality I can't proove

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove this ? I've tried different things but it gave me something different.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\,\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{1+i}\,\right) = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

Comment: This is telescoping...

Comment: Write out all the terms in full for say, n=4, and see what happens.

Comment: Have you try to write it down explicitly for a certain n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to express the terms in this form:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{1+i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+i}.
$$
On the second sum, we can use the substitution $j=i+1$.  Since $i$ starts at $1$ and ends at $n$, $j$ starts at $2$ and ends at $n+1$, so we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{1+i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{j}.
$$
Suppose that we separte the first term of the first sum and the last term of the second sum, then we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{1+i}\right)=\frac{1}{1}+\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
Observe that the two inner sums are exactly the same (just with a different variable of summation).  Therefore, the two sums cancel out, leaving
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{1+i}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$

This could also be proved by induction, but I leave that up to you to try.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{1+i}\right)=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+i}=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{j}\\
=1+ \sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{n+1}
=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
where we set $j=1+i$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}\right)&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

An inductive proof works quite nicely.

If $n=1$ there's not much to show:
$$\sum_{i=1}^1\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}=1-\frac{1}{2}=1-\frac{1}{1+1}.$$
Now suppose the formula holds for some natural number $n$ and show it holds for $n+1$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{1}{n+2}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)+1}.
\end{align}
Hence the result holds for all natural numbers $n$.